# Decimal expansion of irrational numbers?

Tags: soft-question, irrational-numbers

Apologies if this is a trivial question. Is there any particular study which deals with the properties of decimal expansions of irrational numbers? Studies that deal with patterns and so on. Are there any books or some significant papers on this?

Comment: You may find the term "normal number" (and its variants) a good starting point.

Comment: Not "trivial", but as stated, this question is far too broad. Because as you know, irrational numbers are those which have decomal expansions which are not eventually periodic, and conversely, as soon as you have some decimal exapnsion which is not eventuall periodic, you have an irrational number. Hence, so far you are asking what is known about *all sequences of digits except the ones that are eventually periodic*. Well there are many. -- To even start making sense, you would have to specify if you want your irrational numbers to have some property (algebraic, of certain degree, ...).

Comment: Okay, specifically I’m looking at studies on the digits of the decimal expansion. Say for example $m$ consecutive digits of an irrational number, and the linear dependence of these digits and so on.